# Apache camel sql parameter for sql database name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-camel

I am trying to use a parameter in camel from the camel context in a sql query as the database name.

Using a parameter like this works fine

```
<to uri="sql:UPDATE log SET field = :#value" />
```

But when I try to use it like this

```
<to uri="sql:UPDATE log_:#parameter SET field = :#value" />
```

It doesn't work - apparently because camel inserts the parameter with apostrophes producing this as a table name: log_'value' which  is not valid.

So how could I prevent camel from inserting apostrophes before and after the parameter? Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You cannot simply parametrize table name, you need to use Dynamic-SQL.

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html